# how to theme the read more link using fields mode in views,

Tags: views

In views i have created a block view in where i want to list only the titles of 5 nodes,
using the 'field' setting in views.
Under 'pager' i have set the amount of items accordingly.
I have enabled 'the read more' link in case more nodes show up.

My problem is that when my read more link shows up it is way out of line with the listing.(right side)

With my chrome element inspector i set the aligning of the read more link to left which is acceptable.

How can i accomplish this with in my drupal set up.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Simply place the changes you made in inspector into your themes CSS file, and flush the cache if you are not seeing your changes immediately.

Comment: According to the inspector the aligned setting is specified in .more-link however this is not written in my style.css nor can i find it in the other css files of my (corporate clean)theme. What am i missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be making any theme changes in a sub theme, rather than editing the actual theme files. This is so all of your changes are not wiped out when an update is available for corporate clean.

Please read https://www.drupal.org/node/225125 for more information on sub theming.

As for the changes to be made to your stylesheet, open your style.css in an editor such as notepad++ and add the following lines (if align left is what you need)

```
.more-link {
  text-align:left;
}
```